# How automatically add info, specified during registration, to "Profile"? Django 2.1.5

Tags: python, django

I matched `Profile` with `User` by `OneToOne` with signals.
I created `SignUpForm` with additional fields (`location`, `email`, `firstname` etc) and email confirmation.

How make the this info (`location`, `email`, `firstname` etc) automacally added to `Profile`?

I think, this really make with

```
user.refresh_from_db()
user.profile.<...>=form.cleaned_data.get('<...>')
```

but I don't know how.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='', null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='', null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["location"]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    location = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'location', 'password1', 'password2')


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ('user', )
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'location', 'email', 'first_name')
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

template **profile_detail.html**

```
...
<h1>User: {{ profile.user }}</h1>
  <p>{{ profile.first_name|safe }}</p>
  <p>{{ profile.email|safe }}</p>
  <p>{{ profile.location|safe }}</p>
...
```

Comment: Where is the profile form being used?

Comment: On the site, each user has his own profile.

Comment: But you haven't shown it being used in a view. Where exactly is the user entering the profile information?

Comment: User entered info during registration (in SignUpForm). What and where to write in views.py that the info automatically saved in "Profile", I don't know?

Comment: maybe more problem in signals.py?

Comment: I added profile template code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can put the additional data in the `view` method . You can try like this:

```
# form

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    location = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'location', 'password1', 'password2')

# view

def signup(request):
   ...
   location = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
   user = form.save(commit=False)
   user.is_active = False
   user.save()
   profile = user.profile
   profile.location = location
   profile.save()
   ...
```

Here I am not adding *email* and *firstname* in the form or in the profile, because if you are using default `auth.User` model, then these data are available in the Model already. For that, please see then [AbstractBaseUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L289) implementation.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to call `user.save()` before calling `user.profile`. Please see the updated answer