# cannot auto create profile when registered new user from link

Tags: django, user-profile

## Problem :

user's profile hasn't be created through "Sign Up" link(new user register) but able to created in only admin page.

## view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def register_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created!!!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register_users.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!!!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
    'u_form': u_form,
    'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile_users.html',context)
```

## model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='abc.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email    = forms.EmailField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        ]

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email    = forms.EmailField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
        'username',
        'email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

## signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

## profile_users.html

```
{% extends 'postorder/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
  <div class="media">
    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
      <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
　　<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile info!</legend>
            {{ u_form|crispy }}
            {{ p_form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update!</button>
        </div>
　</form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

## register_users.html

```
{% extends 'postorder/base_postorder.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">SUBMIT NOW!</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                ALready Have an Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In!</a>
            </small>
        </div>

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

- app.py applied signal

What 's wrong with the code?
Apologize in advance for long code as newbie don't know where is the problem since different approach accumulated.

- followed by this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4jPR-M0TAQ&t=2292s&list=WL&index=6

Comment: are you sure user is created ?

Comment: Ahtisham, the new registered users can be found in admin page but their profile donnot exist as @receiver suppose to be done automatically .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after adding this script in *int*.py file , never been thought its need to be edited .
Still helpful if someone can tell the reason.

```
# _int_.py
default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'
```

Comment: Imm following same tutorial to create a user profile on registration.. However the code doesn't create any user profile not even in the Admin page.. It only allows me to create user profile manually from admin page, any suggestion?

Comment: I tried adding "default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'" in my init.py file but i stil get same error.

Answer (score 1):

[Watch this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179535/how-automatically-add-info-specified-during-registration-to-profile-django)

I think you need to remove *form.save()* and to ad this code (after *if form.is_valid())*

**views.py**

```
def register_view(request):
    ....
    <your_field_from_registration> = form.cleaned_data.get('<your_field_from_registration>')
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    user.save()
    profile = user.profile
    ....
    profile.<your_field_from_registration> = <your_field_from_registration>
    ....
    profile.save()
    ....
```

Comment: you cannot copy paste someone else answer as your.

Comment: Thankyou , Retried as the link you posted . ERROR : RelatedObjectDoesNotExist --  profile = user.profile <--- No GET data . Can i gusess my signal.py wasn't properly created 'profile' instance therefore no 'user.profile' to retrieve ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and you have to create a function in apps.py in AppConfig class:

```
class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'

    # for signals.property
    def ready(self):
        import accounts.signals
```